# What to do when a user asks the same question on two SO Family sites and the original gets migrated

Tags: discussion, moderators

This question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/31361/how-to-calibrate-my-monitor) was migrated to SU *after* the OP, listening to a comment left for him, asked the same [question there already](https://superuser.com/questions/31360/how-to-calibrate-my-monitor).

I don't have the rep to vote to close on SU, and I flag for moderator attention seems a bit harsh.

** Update **

Thanks, I flagged the migrated version and included the question # in the explanation. The full link was too long for the text box.

Answer (score 7):

The flag for moderator attention isn't supposed to be a harsh thing. Use it whenever you think something needs to be done that you yourself can't do.

For example, feel free to use the moderator flag in the following situations (and many more!):

- You see a post that has an abusive tag (<kbd>please-send-teh-codez</kbd>) but you don't have 250 reputation points yet
- You see a post that needs to be migrated
- You see a post that needs to be closed
- You feel someone is abusing the voting mechanism
- A user has somehow created multiple accounts that need merging
- You want your reputation recalculated
- You see similar questions that might be merged
- A question should be made community wiki

Comment: You really get things like "I need my tires changed"?

Comment: For the record, I change my own tires because I am just that manly.

Comment: "A question should be made community wiki", this is definitely not a reason to flag for moderator attention

Comment: Sure it is.

Comment: @Juan: Atwood disagrees: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183

Comment: The moderators have the power to wikify any question. With a single click. Including the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing *is* to flag it for moderator attention and explain the situation. In this case, I'd recommend merging the migrated question into the question that he re-asked since it looks like he doesn't have ownership of the migrated question, and since both questions have answers.

Answer (score 0):

Flag for moderator, explaining it. The moderator will (I hope, at least) just close one of the two questions as a duplicate of the other, depending on which one has answers/upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have merged the two questions. Interestingly they were one question ID apart. Well spotted.

Comment: The OP posted the new question as a comment in the migrated question So it wasn't rocket science. I too found it interesting that they were only 1 ID apart.